# Android BLE scan not showing Arduino 101 device

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am running into an issue where my Arduino 101 device will not be discovered by a BLE scan. However, if I scan for normal bluetooth devices it shows up.

I am attempting to use the BLE Gatt example by Google here https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/project.html but the device does not show. Even with the unmodified code.

However if I query for connected bluetooth devices it shows my device.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
String name = "";
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
    if (device.getName().equals("B & S")) {
        bsDevice = device;
        name += device.getName();
    }
}
```

If I attempt to connect to the device using `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID)` or `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` I get an error

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
socket = bsDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
socket.connect();
```

I am using an app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en, that allows me to connect to the device but the characteristics that it shows is byte information and is cryptic.

How should I properly connect to the Arduino 101 BLE device?